# LINQ & SQL query help: Doing a distinct on two columns together?

Tags: sql, linq

How can I do a `SELECT` where I get the `DISTINCT` result based on the `FromLinkID` AND `ToLinkID` together?

If I have a `List` with the following data, how could I get what I am after in LINQ?

[image]

Comment: What would you expect the output to be on the above data?

Comment: Why `sql` and `linq`: did you want a LINQ query, or a SQL statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT FromLinkId, ToLinkId
FROM    mytable
```

To select one record per `(FromLinkId, ToLinkId)` (that with the least `id`), assuming `SQL Server`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FromLinkId, ToLinkId ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        ) q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: OMG :) duh - but can I show the rest of the columns as well in the select in there? Which one (incase of distinct) would it show for the rest?

Comment: @VoodooChild: you decide which one to select and I'll write you the query :)

Comment: @Quassnoi: nice, that is brilliant. However I don't see `DISTINCT` keyword in your query, I am assuming `PARTITION BY` does the same thing? I guess `GROUP BY` is about the same thing?

Comment: @Voodoo: yes, along with `WHERE rn = 1`.

Comment: @Voodoo: `GROUP BY` shrinks all records from the group into one, analytics functions (like `ROW_NUMBER()`) don't.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thanks! any idea how I would go about doing this in LINQ? I have the `List` with the data I posted in my question and I want to get, what you helped me with, in code?

Comment: @Voodoo: sorry, I'm not a `LINQ` expert :(

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thanks for your help and I posted a LINQ answer which does what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Select Distinct FromLinkId LinkId From MyTable 
Union 
Select Distinct ToLinkId LinkId From MyTable
```

Comment: Sir, this doesn't work. It gives me both rows from my sample data in the question.

Comment: @Voodoo,  This is what you need to get a set of distinct values from the combined set of all FromLinkId and ToLinkId values.  It seems that you actually want the set of distinct pairs, or tuples, of (FromLinkId, ToLinkId) values, which case Quassnoi answer is the sql you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, FromLinkId, ToLinkId FROM MyTable GROUP BY FromLinkId, ToLinkId -- if there are more than one record with the same (FromLinkId, ToLinkId) pair, only one of them is displayed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
SELECT MAX(ID), MAX(Name), FromLinkID, ToLinkID FROM MyTable 
GROUP BY FromLinkID, ToLinkID
```

Or even:

```
SELECT t.* FROM
(SELECT MAX(ID) as MaxID, FromLinkID, ToLinkID FROM MyTable  
GROUP BY FromLinkID, ToLinkID) d 
LEFT JOIN MyTable t ON d.MaxID=t.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ solution:

```
List<MyObj> distinctResults = allResults
  .GroupBy(p => new {p.FromLinkID, p.ToLinkID} )
  .Select(g => g.First())
  .ToList();
```

hope it helps someone.

[Helpful related SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property)

Answer (score 0):

List distinctResults = allResults
  .Select(p => new {p.FromLinkID, p.ToLinkID} )
  .Distinct()
  .ToList();